# Why can't I find service discovery in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I am creating a simple grpc example using Kubernetes in an on-premises environment.

When nodejs makes a request with pythonservice, pythonservice responds with helloworld and displays it on a web page.

However, pythonservice's clusterip is accessible, but not `http://pythoservice:8000`.

There may be a problem with coredns, so I checked various things and deleted kube-dns service of kube-system.

And if you check with `pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local` with nslookup, you will see a different address from the clusterip of pythonservice.
Sorry I'm not good at English

This is the node.js code :

```
var setting = 'test';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const port = 80;
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/helloworld.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
    });

// http://pythonservice:8000
// 10.109.228.152:8000
// pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local:8000
// 218.38.137.28

var hello_proto = 
grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).helloworld;

function main(callback) {
  var client = new hello_proto.Greeter("http://pythonservice:8000", 
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

  var user;
  if (process.argv.length >= 3) {
    user = process.argv[2];
  } else {
    user = 'world';
  }
  client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('Greeting:', response.message);
    setting = response.message;
  });
}

var server = app.listen(port, function () {});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    main();    
    res.send(setting);
    //res.send(ip2);
    //main(function(result){
      //  res.send(result);
    //})
});
```

This is the yaml file for pythonservice

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: practice-dp2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: practice-dp2
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: practice-dp2
    spec:
      hostname: appname
      subdomain: default-subdomain
      containers:
      - name: practice-dp2
        image: taeil777/greeter-server:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pythonservice
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: practice-dp2
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
```

this is kubectl get all:

```
root@pusik-server0:/home/tinyos/Desktop/grpc/node# kubectl get all
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/practice-dp-55dd4b9d54-v4hhq   1/1     Running   1          68m
pod/practice-dp2-7d4886876-znjtl   1/1     Running   0          18h


NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   
PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        
443/TCP    34d
service/nodeservice     ClusterIP   10.100.165.53    <none>        
80/TCP     68m
service/pythonservice   ClusterIP   10.109.228.152   <none>        
8000/TCP   18h


NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/practice-dp    1/1     1            1           68m
deployment.apps/practice-dp2   1/1     1            1           18h

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   
AGE
replicaset.apps/practice-dp-55dd4b9d54   1         1         1       
68m
replicaset.apps/practice-dp2-7d4886876   1         1         1       
18h
```

```
root@pusik-server0:/home/tinyos/Desktop/grpc/python# nslookup 
pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 218.38.137.28
```

Comment: You will need to recreate coredns which is used for service discovery, make sure it is up and running properly. Can you post your yaml file for the pythonservice, the output of running ```kubectl get svc``` and the output of the nslookup?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Posted as you said.
practice-dp = node js
pracice-dp2 = python

Comment: Seems like you are running nslookup on your host machine? Try running is inside one pod. If 127.0.1.1 is the DNS server on your host machine, this may cause coredns failed to start. Take a look at the following link. https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/loop/README.md#troubleshooting-loops-in-kubernetes-clusters

Comment: I am trying to run nslookup inside the pod but I get the following error:
--------------------------------------------
    kubectl exec practice-dp-55dd4b9d54-v4hhq -- nslookup 
    pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local
    OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting 
    container process caused "exec: \"nslookup\": executable file not found in 
    $PATH": unknown
    command terminated with exit code 126
---------------------

I then configured a cluster via virtualbox in ubuntu environment.
1 master node, 1 worker node

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Answering the first question:

- `pythonservice's clusterip is accessible, but not http://pythoservice:8000`.

Please refer to [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)

The type of `service/pythonservice` is `ClusterIP` If you are interested with exposing the service outside the cluster please use service type `NodePort or LoadBalancer`. According to the attached screens, your application is accessible from within the cluster (ClusterIP serice).

**2**. Answering the second question:

- The output
  `exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"nslookup\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown command terminated with exit code 126`

means that inside your pod probably you don't have tools like `nslookup` so: please run some pod in the same namespace with installed tools and verify again:

```
kubectl run ubuntu --rm -it --image ubuntu --restart=Never --command -- bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install dnsutils && bash'

kubectl exec ubuntu2 -- nslookup pythonservice.default.svc.cluster.local
```

-- **Update**

Please verfify the state for all pods and svc especially in the `kube-system` namespace:

```
kubectl get nodes,pods,svc --all-namespaces -o wide
```

In order to start debugging please get more information about particular problem f.e. with coredns please use:

```
kubectl describe pod your coredns_pod -n kube-system
kubectl logs coredns_pod -n kube-system
```

Please refer to:

- [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)
- [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

But in 2, the command to create ubuntu pod shows an error ...

Comment: I tried to use nslookup by going to kubectl exec {podname} -ti bash to use nslookup in pod, but apt-get dnsutils does not run.

Should installation be done for nslookup in Dockerfile ??

Comment: By installing dnsutill in a Dockerfile, you can use nslookup on containers in pods. However
 I get the following error:

';; connection timed out; no servers could be reached '

Comment: I have updated the answer: For the second command `kubectl run ubuntu --rm -it --image ubuntu ...` please provide output with the error info.
It's not necessary to build image using docker file in order to use `dnsutils` in container with ubuntu image.
Please provide: full commands used, full error info, and cluster state (pods,svc,version)